# Underscore: Losing reference to collection when filtering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using backbone's fetch() to fetch my collection. As this takes a lot of time and will be frequently filtered so there is no need to fetch() it multiple times. I'm trying to do this like:

```
if(!App.fetch){
   App.fetch = new App.Collection.Artists();
   App.fetch.fetch()
}                
var c = _.filter(App.fetch.models, function(model){
     return model.get('date') == day && model.get('stage') == stage
});
var c = new App.Collection.Artists(c);
```

What I think I'm doing: if there is no cached collection, create one and fetch it. I'll be able to use this function with different "day" and "stage" values to filter App.fetch, which was populated only once and not touched again.

When I log the on.('change') event on collection I get change event fired. My guess is that filter method fires the change event and the result is that it only works the first time!

My question is why is it not how I think I'm doing and how would I tackle this problem.

EDIT: The problem is that the second time this function is called, I get returned 0 models to the collection 'c'.

Sincerely, Jan

Answer (score 1):

You are treating an asynchronous call in a synchronous manner. Try something like this, with adjusting variables scope as needed:

```
App.fetch({
      success: function() {
        var c = _.filter(App.fetch.models, function(model){
             return model.get('date') == day && model.get('stage') == stage
        });
        var c = new App.Collection.Artists(c);
       }
   });
```